# Passing Objects from Activity to Fragments is Pass by Reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, pass-by-reference, parcelable, pass-by-value

When we use `Serializable` and `Parcelable` to pass object between `activities` then a **copy/value of the object** is sent to the receiving `activity`(Typical Pass by value behaviour).

But why is it that when we pass objects to `Fragments` as `Parcelable` inside `Bundle`, for some reason they are sent as **reference of object** instead of **copy/value of the object** (Pass by Reference behaviour).I haven't checked this out for `Serializable` but i believe it would be the same.

The object is passed the same way so why is there a difference in how the `Activity` receives the `object` and how the `Fragment` receives it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why is it that when we pass objects to Fragments as Parcelable inside Bundle, for some reason they are sent as reference of object instead of copy/value of the object

That is not guaranteed. For example, if you undergo a configuration change, or your process is terminated but the user returns to your task quickly, you will get a copy.

> The object is passed the same way so why is there a difference in how the Activity receives the object and how the Fragment receives it ?

Starting an activity always involves IPC, and therefore always involves copying data across process boundaries.

Comment: so how can one ensure that the we always get the `copy`  instead of `reference` when we are passing objects to fragments ?

Also do you think that Passing of Objects by Reference in case of fragments is a bug in Android implementation?

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji: "so how can one ensure that the we always get the copy instead of reference when we are passing objects to fragments ?" -- don't pass custom `Parcelable` objects. Or, make a copy yourself on the publishing side. Or, make a copy yourself on the receiving side. Or, do not call any setters on the objects in the fragment. Or, do not pass data this way, but instead use some singleton data model manager. "Also do you think that Passing of Objects by Reference in case of fragments is a bug in Android implementation?" -- no. It could use more documentation.

Comment: its a little hard to understand that people have not been facing this problem in Android Development. Can you link me to some articles or answers where this problem is explained with some references to official Android docs

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question, and I think it's passing the reference.

```
   public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    if (mIndex >= 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already active");
    }
    mArguments = args;
}

/**
 * Return the arguments supplied when the fragment was instantiated,
 * if any.
 */
final public Bundle getArguments() {
    return mArguments;
}
```

I found this from Fragment source code, it's different with activities passing data, although they both use `Bundle`.